# Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

```
a=int(input("please input number of players  "))
while (a < 2):
a=int(input("please input at least two players  "))
if (a==2):
p1=input("please enter name for player 1  ")
p2=input("please enter name for player 2  ")
x=float(input("please enter initiative for "+(p1)))
y=float(input("please enter initiative for "+(p2)))
x=x,p1
y=y,p2
if (x > y):
    lowest=y
    highest=x
elif(y > x):
    lowest=x
    highest=y
print(lowest)
steps=int(input("Please enter number of steps for "+(lowest)+" action" ))
```

i have tried everything i can think of and it needs to do this but i can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Where are you specifically having a problem?

Comment: While for other languages posting unindented code is just bad habit, for Python makes the code impossible to test; fix the indentation.

Comment: `lowest, highest = sorted((x, y))` saves 5 lines, and prevents crashing when `x==y`

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what the message say: in the last line, in the subexpression

```
"Please enter number of steps for "+(lowest)+" action"
```

you are trying to concatenate a string with a tuple (`lowest` - since it is either `x` or `y`, and both of them are tuples due to the assignment `x=x,p1` and `y=y,p2`), which would require an implicit conversion from tuple to string.

To fix this, you have to convert explicitly the tuple to string (`str(lowest)`) (although I suspect that you actually want just one of the elements of the tuple to be displayed).

Comment: I'm trying to get it to display the lowest persons name in that line but i don't know how to write it. so if that would fix it how would i need to put it in there?

Comment: You put the person name in the second element of the tuple, so now you just have to access it...